# Python: ImportError: No module named _pluggy

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, pytest-cov

I am getting `ImportError: No module named _pluggy` error when running tests using pytest.

Then I tried installing pluggy using `pip install pluggy`. It installs `pluggy==0.6.0` successfully, but is still giving the error.

**Versions List** (From running `pip freeze | grep pytest`)

- pytest==3.3.1
- pytest-cov==2.5.1
- pytest-metadata==1.5.0
- pytest-runner==3.0
- pluggy==0.6.0
- Python 2.7.12

Shown below is the stack trace

Tests run successfully when run in a virtualenv. What are the possible causes which can cause this error in a non-virtualenv environment?

Comment: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2960 mentions that particular error - is that any help?

Comment: @bouteillebleu Awesome. Upgrading pytest-metadata solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Excellent, glad it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was pointed out by @bouteillebleu the issue was in pytest-metadata package.

The solution was to upgrade the package

```
pip install --upgrade pytest-metadata
```